# Why no access before IP address set?

Tags: networking, routes, ip

The situation is: I am running an embedded system on a VMWare virtual machine, by default the IP address of the network port is 192.168... When I try to get files from a TFTP server that is already set up, a connection failure occurred. However, after I set the IP address of the port to an valid IP allocated for me, the problem was solved.

I am wondering the reason of it. (I know it might be a basic networking question)

BTW, how is the routing set up when I set an IP address to an virtual machine in a situation like this?

Comment: "I went to make lunch, but the house hadn't been build yet. why is there no kitchen counter"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networking and virtual machines. This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address is basically the name of the machine. If the machine do not know its name, it is unable to determine whether the message on the network is for it and therefore just ignores it.

As long as all computers you want to connect are on the same network, both physically and in the same IP network, you need no router and all your routing will get itself done just from correct IP address and network mask.

If you, however, intend to let your virtual machine connect to the outer world, you have several options:
 - Hide virtual machine behind NAT on the host (PAT to be precise)
 - Give virtual machine full control over the network interface
 - Configure your host as a router
Those options are usually available in the virtualization software.

Finally, I'd suggest reading some networking tutorials. Unfortunately, I can recall only the http://tcpipguide.com/ at the moment.

And BTW: This question belongs to superuser.com, not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The ip address is the logical address of your device .

[ip address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)

any one who wants to transfer data with he must have an ip and knows your ip(as the phone number).

usually the ip is assigned automatically by the DHCP(The Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol)
[Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)

but in your case maybe this service is disabled ,

so you have to assign your ip manually.